# How to print output side by side?

Tags: awk

i have the following output from a script:

```
192.168.0.10
192.168.0.10
undefined
192.168.0.130
192.168.0.130
ansible
192.168.0.141
192.168.0.141
undefined
192.168.0.252
192.168.0.252
undefined
```

but i want it to be like:

```
192.168.0.10 192.168.0.10 undefined
192.168.0.130 192.168.0.130 ansible
192.168.0.141 192.168.0.141 undefined
192.168.0.252 192.168.0.252 undefined
```

i have seen how to get 2 lines next to each other but i fail at 3 ^^

```
awk '{getline b;printf("%s %s\n",$0,b)}'
```

Comment: pr is more suited for this: `pr -3ats' ' ip.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk` could you please try following.

```
awk '{count++;printf("%s%s",$0,count%3==0?ORS:OFS)} END{if(count%3!=0){print ""}}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                       ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  count++                                   ##Increasing variable count value with 1 here.
  printf("%s%s",$0,count%3==0?ORS:OFS)      ##Printing current line and either new line(ORS) or space(OFS) based opon condition if count is divided by 3 or NOT.
}
END{                                        ##Starting END block for this awk code here.
  if(count%3!=0){                           ##Checking condition if count is NOT fully divided by 3 then do following.
    print ""                                ##Printing null variable here in case previous line was not having new line so to add it in last.
  }
}
'  Input_file                               ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using paste.

```
paste - - - < file.txt
```

To use just a space delimiter.

```
paste -d ' ' - - - < file.txt
```